# GLKit detect touch location

Tags: iphone, touch, glkit

how can i detect touch location on iphone GLKit 3d object?

if it on the object?
and where?

i have cube that build from triangles, i need to know on touch even if it was on the object and if so where

my cube:

```
const Vertex Vertices[] = {
// Front - red
{{1, -1, 1}, {0.89, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {0.89, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
{{-1, 1, 1}, {0.89, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
{{-1, -1, 1}, {0.89, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
// Back - green
{{1, 1, -1}, {0, 0.92, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
{{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 0.92, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
{{1, -1, -1}, {0, 0.92, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
{{-1, 1, -1}, {0, 0.92, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
// Left - yellow
{{-1, -1, 1}, {1, 0.92, 0, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
{{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 0.92, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
{{-1, 1, -1}, {1, 0.92, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 0.92, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
// Right - blue
{{1, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0.89, 1}, {1, 0}},
{{1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 0.89, 1}, {1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0.89, 1}, {0, 1}},
{{1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0.89, 1}, {0, 0}},
// Top
{{1, 1, 1}, {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {1, 0}},
{{1, 1, -1}, {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {1, 1}},
{{-1, 1, -1},{0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {0, 1}},
{{-1, 1, 1}, {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {0, 0}},
// Bottom
{{1, -1, -1}, {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {1, 0}},
{{1, -1, 1}, {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {1, 1}},
{{-1, -1, 1}, {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
{{-1, -1, -1}, {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1}, {0, 0}}
```

};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    // Front
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    // Back
    4, 6, 5,
    4, 5, 7,
    // Left
    8, 9, 10,
    10, 11, 8,
    // Right
    12, 13, 14,
    14, 15, 12,
    // Top
    16, 17, 18,
    18, 19, 16,
    // Bottom
    20, 21, 22,
    22, 23, 20
};

Answer (score 0):

1. Transform the coordinates of the touch into a ray in eye space, going from the near plane to the far plane.
2. Transform the vertices of the cube into eye space (same transformation as you use when you render it).
3. Do a ray-box intersection test against the transformed cube.